# Efficiently return a value from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have  query which returns single value (i.e) count. I'm exceuting it using the stored procedure in the following way and using  execute reader with dataset to get single value

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCnt
@EmpNo char(4)
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   Declare @Cnt int
   SELECT @Cnt = count(*)
   FROM employees
   WHERE EMPLNO = @EmpNo
      AND test = 'p'            

   BEGIN 
      SELECT @Cnt
   END
END
```

is this effcient way 
or Do I need to use  the execute.scalar() and return value directly from the query instead of assigning to @cnt 
can any one advise me

Comment: Seems ok, except you don't need an extra `BEGIN .... END` around the final `SELECT` statement .... Since this stored proc returns exactly one row and one column, you would typically use `var result = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` from .NET to call this

Comment: Since you are retunring a result set with a single row with a single column, you should use ExecuteScaler. Its optomised for that situation.

Comment: try it both ways and see... I doubt it'll make much of a difference anyway.

Comment: Ok execute scalar in more optimised than execute reader in  this situation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to create the variable.  You just need the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCnt
@EmpNo char(4)
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   SELECT count(1)
   FROM employees
   WHERE EMPLNO = @EmpNo
      AND test = 'p'            
END
```

Since this is only one value being returned from the stored procedure, you will likely want to use `ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: @gbn No reason other than habit I guess, since it is equivalent to `COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 1):

All [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) does is get the first field from the first record.

Can't you just `SELECT` the count directly?

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT Count(*) FROM employees WHERE EMPLNO = @EmpNo AND test='p'
END
```